# Mobaxterm does not work using vnc session

Tags: vnc-viewer, mobaxterm

when I use mobaxterm to connect my work PC by vnc option, I get error "***no configured security type is supported by 3.3 vnc viewer*** "

I searched and find that setting encryption to "***let vnc server choose***" or "***prefer on***" can solve this situation.

but mobaxterm seems to have no option to set this. And unfortunately I can not change  my work pc(server) vnc setting, only IT department has the permission

so it means mobaxterm is not fit for me?

Answer (score 0):

Many VNC clients may not work with the newest security options that are present in the VNC Server that is provided with Raspberry Pi OS. You might see an error like this “vnc no matching security types” or "no configured security type is supported by 3.3 vnc viewer"

The solution for the home network is to downgrade the security options on the server:

Edit this file:
/root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11

It contains 2 line in my version (Bullseye)

Add these lines to the end of the file:

```
Authentication=VncAuth

Encryption=AlwaysOff

Password=e0fd0472492935da
```

Change the password like this:

```
sudo vncpasswd -service
```

You will be prompted for the new password

Then reboot the Pi

Comment: Tried this and it solved the original problem but now I just get "Failed to connect to server"

Answer (score 0):

Real VNC Server 6.10.1 on ubuntu 22
MobaXterm v22.1 on windows11

vnc server options

/security tab
encryption: prefer off
authentication: vnc password

/Users & Permissions tab
set password

succeed!